# Django filter returns queryset with ID instead of username

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Hi guys so I have a search function but when using the .objects.filter() method I get a queryset that shows an ID instead of the username.

This is the view:

```
def search_expense(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_str = json.loads(request.body).get('searchText')
        expenses = Expense.objects.filter(
            amount__istartswith=search_str) | Expense.objects.filter(
            date__icontains=search_str) | Expense.objects.filter(
            description__icontains=search_str) | Expense.objects.filter(
            category__icontains=search_str)
        data = expenses.values()
        return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

> <QuerySet [{'id': 16, 'amount': 2.33, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 10, 2), 'description': 'Something', **'owner_id': 1**, 'category': 'Food'}]>

So instead of the 'owner_id': 1 I need it to be 'owner': username

The model (the User model is Django's standard model):

```
class Expense(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField(default=now)
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

    class Meta:
        ordering: ['-date']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new fields to [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values).

```
from django.db.models import F
fields = tuple(x.name for x in Expense._meta.get_fields())
data = expenses.values(*fields, owner_name=F("owner__value"))
```

You will also have to specify all the fields you want manually, or if you want all the fields then you can just use [`.get_fields()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields) like I have done.

You have to name the new field something other than "owner", or you will get a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: The annotation 'owner' conflicts with a field on the model.
```

Showing the ID of ForeignKey fields is the intended behaviour of `.values()` according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values):

> If you have a field called `foo` that is a `ForeignKey`, the default `values()` call will return a dictionary key called `foo_id`, since this is the name of the hidden model attribute that stores the actual value (the `foo` attribute refers to the related model).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation as to why .values() gives foo_id. I've come across an error:

`
NameError: name 'F' is not defined
`

Comment: I've added the import for `F`.

Comment: You, my friend, are a gem. Thank you for your thorough answer!